# Data binding with merge not working if the layout is included in sameLayout multiple times

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments, data-binding

Here is my layout to include inside main layout.

```
<!--item_card_data.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="@layout/fragment_order_confirmation">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvCardTextTitle"
        android:text="@string/card_title_customer_id"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_light"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_m"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/margin_2"
        android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_regular"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_6"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvCardTextTitleData"
        android:text="@string/card_title_customer_id_data"

        android:textColor="@color/black_medium"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_l"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/margin_2"
        android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_22"
        />
</merge>
```

Here is my main layout

```
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        >
                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/layout_item_customerid"
                            layout="@layout/item_card_data"
                         />
                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/layout_item_customerid1"
                            layout="@layout/item_card_data"
                         />
                         <include
                            android:id="@+id/layout_item_customerid2"
                            layout="@layout/item_card_data"
                         />

                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

It throws following error:

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID**

I tried working with this link:
https://betterprogramming.pub/exploring-viewbinding-in-depth-598925821e41

But it don't work as expected when  is used multiple times *within same layout*.

Comment: You should post the code that causes null pointer exception and the logcat entries for the error. That will help.

Comment: @Cheticamp if i remove id from include tag, it works. But i want to reuse same layout multiple times with different data in just single activity_main.xml file